# What are Range hood exhaust exterior wall location requirements?

Tags: range, hood

What are the requirements for a residential range hood exhaust location on the exterior wall?

Comment: Are you looking for code requirements or practical requirements?  For code questions, include your location.

Comment: Prince George’s county Maryland. No other air intake near and no other house or public within 500 or more feet.  Soffits 11 feet above possible exit, but windows within 2.5 on either side and one within 4 feet above and 8 feet above ground level.  A natural gas range top, makeup air vent location not an issue.